# Spring, JPA, Hibernate, Atomikos - strange startup error

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, atomikos

As it is stated in thread title, we are using Spring framework, JPA with hibernate provider and Atomikos as transaction provider.

Mostly this set up is working, but there are strange warnings during startup of a Tomcat:

```
WARN : atomikos - Local heuristic termination of coordinator 127.0.1.1.tm0000100030 with state COMMITTING
```

it is repeated few times, but with different numbers, like `tm0000300030`

What is the cause of this warning? Does atomikos try to store something in database during startup of an application and he is stopped during commiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in Atomikos, see [this discussion](http://fogbugz.atomikos.com/default.asp?community.6.2615.3).

I also had about four of theses messages with Spring + OpenJPA + Derby + Tomcat, just before the JTA transaction manager kicked in. We used Atomikos only in automated integration tests, so I never really cared.